# Changing text in Ubercart form

Tags: ubercart

I am using Drupal 6 with Ubercart 6.x-2.9. In checkout, I dont need my customers to fill out their address - I just need name and email. So I have removed the address fields within the 'Billing information' part of the form.

When the customer gets to the 'Review Order' page, it lists the name and address with the label 'Address:'. As I only have the first and last name fields, I wish to change 'Address:' to 'Name:'.

Strangely, I cant seem to find anywhere where this 'Address' label is set (I did a text search in all files and searched through the database). Can anyone help please.

Comment: I wrote in [this post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79062/how-to-change-the-error-system-messages/79068#79068) to override strings.

Answer (score 1):

There is [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides)

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found this which might help you change the name of the address field to name. The example is for first name but it shouldnt be too difficult todo the same thing for address.
http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/14998/problem_uc_get_field_name_and_translatation_address_text_field_names

```
function uc_get_field_name($field) {
$fields = array(
'first_name' => t('First name'),

to

function uc_get_field_name($field) {
$fields = array(
'first_name' => t('Test name'),
```

If this doesnt answer your question. I will alter my answer to accommodate your changes.