# How to change the error system messages

Tags: 7, string-overrides

is it possilbe to use [string overrides module](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) for system messages? What i need is to change the order of the words and add some more. For example i have a webform with some required fields. When user forget to fill a field it gets this message: "Surname field is required.". I need to change this to "The field Surname is required for this form". How can i do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [String Overrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module. Also you can override strings through settings.php, look [this](https://drupal.org/node/522036) post.

For example that you listed above, there is one string that contains variable !name. So "Surname field is required." is "!name field is required.", when you changing use "The field !name is required for this form" and you overrides all similar messages.